# StaticInjectionError running Ionic tests with Karma

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run a simple test to check that a component is created.

When I am running the test with karma `karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js`, I get the following output:

```
10 10 2018 10:50:22.316:ERROR [HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Linux 0.0.0) | Create account component | should be created]: Error: StaticInjectorError(t)[t -> t]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 't', Function ], ngDebugContext: t({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33603585, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 49152, directChildFlags: 49152, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 1, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'page-create-account', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 1, flags: 49152, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object, ngContentIndex: -1, childCount: 0,  ...
    at t.get (http://localhost:9876/base/test-config/karma-test-shim.js?6323aa11dcffe596b12ee89cf9d5010482d220c9:45:142)
```

This is the component to test (I reduced to the simplest logic for isolate the problem):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import {UsernameValidator} from "../../validators/username";

@Component({
    selector: 'page-create-account',
    templateUrl: 'create-account.html',
})
export class CreateAccountPage {
    userForm: FormGroup;
    username;
    email;
    password;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        public usernameValidator: UsernameValidator){
        this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
    }
}
```

this is the test:

```
import {async, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {IonicModule, Nav, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {
  UsernameValidatorMock,
  FormBuilderMock,
  NavControllerMock,
  NavMock
} from '../../../test-config/mocks-ionic';
import {CreateAccountPage} from "./create-account";
import {FormBuilder} from "@angular/forms";
import {UsernameValidator} from "../../validators/username";
import {UserService} from "../../services/user.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

describe('Create account component', () => {
  let fixture;
  let component;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CreateAccountPage],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(CreateAccountPage)
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: Nav, useClass: NavMock},
        { provide: NavController, useClass: NavControllerMock},
        { provide: FormBuilder, useClass: FormBuilderMock},
        { provide: UserService, useClass: UserServiceMock},
        { provide: UsernameValidator, useClass: UsernameValidatorMock },
      ]
    })
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateAccountPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component instanceof CreateAccountPage).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

and this is the original UsernameValidator:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class UsernameValidator {

  debouncer: any;
  object_username: any = {};
  constructor(public userService: UserService) {

  }
  checkUsername(control: FormControl): Promise<any> {

    clearTimeout(this.debouncer);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.debouncer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.object_username = {username: control.value};
        this.userService.validateUsername(this.object_username).subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          if ( res === true) {
            resolve({'username taken': true});
          }
        }, (err) => {
          resolve(null);
        });
      }, 1000);

    });
  }
}
```

It seems that is not able to inject some of the providers, but I've already created mocks for all the dependencies used and even for the second level dependencies like UserProvider for UsernameValidator. The test passes successfully without the injection of UsernameValidator. Any idea why this class can not be injected?

Versions:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0, ios 4.5.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally detected the problem. `UserService` depends on `HttpClient` which mock was not included in the providers. That is necessary because `UsernameValidatorMock` is a child class of `UsernameValidator`, then all dependencies of the original class have to be injected.

I could obtain the concrete error:

```
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserService -> HttpClient]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

instead of:

```
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
```

by removing 4.2.0 version of `webpack` (since karma already depends on `webpack`) and downgrading `ts-loader` from 5.4.1 to 3.4.0.

Despite of that, I finally used a spy of the validator class as its shown below:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {

        userValidatorUsernameSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UsernameValidator', ['checkUsername']);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [CreateAccountPage],
          imports: [
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            IonicModule.forRoot(CreateAccountPage)
          ],
          providers: [
            {provide: NavController, useValue: navControllerSpy},
            {provide: NavParams, useFactory: () => NavParamsMock.instance()},
            {provide: Platform, useFactory: () => PlatformMock.instance()},
            {provide: UsernameValidator, useValue: usernameSpy},
          ]
        }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateAccountPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code without your custom classes and it works well.
**In the past, I had several problems with Ionic cli 4 while I use ionic-angular 3.9.2.**

Please **check it again with ionic-cli 3.20.0:**

```
[13:23:07]> (dev)$ionic info

cli packages: (E:\Usuarios\dceresa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 5.0.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2-201807062122
```

Just in case you are curious about my .spec:

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule, Nav, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CreateAccountPage } from "./create-account";
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { NavControllerMock } from 'ionic-mocks';

fdescribe('Create account component', () => {
    let fixture;
    let component;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [CreateAccountPage],
            imports: [
                IonicModule.forRoot(CreateAccountPage)
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: NavController, useClass: NavControllerMock },
                FormBuilder
            ]
        })
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateAccountPage);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(component instanceof CreateAccountPage).toBe(true);
    });

});
```

And the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-create-account',
  templateUrl: 'create-account.html',
})
export class CreateAccountPage {
  userForm: FormGroup;
  username;
  email;
  password;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, check if it's the mocks problem. Try [this](https://github.com/stonelasley/ionic-mocks) for ionic mocks. Works great for most

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the test passes successfully without ```UsernameValidator``` provider. I think is not about downgrading ionic-cli, but in this injection of the class.